# Dynamcially adding panels based on DropdownChoice selection

Tags: wicket

am a newbie to wicket and am experimenting few things with it, like, I have four panel but one only should be added based on the selection made in the DropdownChoice component. 
i tried to add panels using onSelectChange() method, but it doesn't work. can any one please help me out with proper sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I give you an example for this problem. Hope it helps.

```
    DropDownChoice dropDown = new DropDownChoice(...........);
    AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior behavior = new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior(
                            "onchange") {

                @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                  //you should write here the logic that
               // replaces the panel, something like: content.addOrReplace(panel)

                target.addComponent(form);
            }
    };
    dropDown.add(behavior);
```

So that's all, you have to use **AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior** to handle onchange event. If the dropdown menu not a requirement, you can use tabbedpanel. Here you can find the sample code: [wicket tabbed panel](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/ajax/tabbed-panel)

Comment: In most cases it should be easier just to change the visibility of these panels instead of adding or removing them. But in general, this should be the way to go.

Comment: Am using five panels and setting visibility on each will add up more code. But i tried the above soltuions. but i am getting null pointer exception as the first option in the dropdown will null value. I even set the visibility off, but still it throws the same exception. Still trying to handle this

Comment: @lepike: Thank you. That solution worked and i use EmptyPanel on pageload, to handle that null pointer exception.

Comment: i could like to and i tried already but my reputation is low to Vote up :)